# How would I install shutoff valve for fridge water line on current setup

Tags: plumbing

I had a new fridge installed and the plastic water tubing from the sink cold water connection was leaking behind the fridge when they installed it. I am going to replace the plastic tubing and wanted to install a shutoff valve so I would be able to turn off the water to the fridge without having to turn off everything else. The current shut off valve is connected to the tubing I will be removing and I am not a big fan of these types of valves. What is the correct type to use?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would get a valve with 2 outlets, or a dual outlet any plumbing supply or big box stores will have them, this reduces the chance of leaks compared to t's. On a single port valve approx 16$ for a quality brass valve dual 3/8" ports.

Comment: do both of the valves have their own shutoff?

Comment: No they both use the same valve I usually have a shutoff in the wall at the fridge water outlet box (required code for my area) so another shutoff at the source is silly to me

Comment: well i wont have a shutoff in the wall behind the fridge. I am looking for a valve that can have two separate shut offs so I don't think your solutions will work.

Comment: That's how every house I have built and or remodeled worked not having a shutoff at the fridge is a code violation here you might want to check on that.

Comment: Do they make a valve that has 2 separate shut offs? I will not be installing one behind the fridge.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways that you could tee off of the tubing coming out of the wall using fittings, to then attach two separate stop valves.

OR you could splurge and get a double-valve unit:

[image]

Comment: i like that way that one looks. Not sure what size connections i need though. can you tell from the photo?

Comment: Yes, the one depicted will fit your specific scenario. 1/2" nominal compression inlet (for 5/8" O.D. copper pipe) x 3/8" compression outlet (for sink faucet) x 1/4" compression outlet (for refrigerator). This is what your photo *appears* to depict, please confirm prior to buying though...